# How do I extract all data from multiple tables in many word documents in python (Data-Extraction directly from MS Word)?

Tags: python, ms-word, data-extraction

I tried using the below codes but it can only open a document to print the cell text.

The problem is that I have 67 word documents with similar tables, how do I extract all data from tables in each 67 word documents?

Currently the below codes can open only a document to extract cell text in all tables, however, I would like to open multiple word documents in a folder by using the codes below.
Therefore, is there a way to open multiple word documents using the below codes?
 Please help to take a look at the below codes, thanks!!! :((

```
from docx import Documenthttps

wordDoc = Document(r"C:\Users\user\Documents\Lynn\FYPJ P3\FYP (Updated Ver)\FYP\dataprep\documents_sampling\860305644_Cat_5_Patient Care Record (Inpatient Nursing)_Admission.docx")
for table in wordDoc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            print(cell.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this :

```
import os
from docx import Documenthttps

path = '\\some\\path\\to\\folder'
worddocs_list = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    wordDoc = Document(path+"\\"+filename)
    worddocs_list.append(wordDoc)

for wordDoc in worddocs_list:
    for table in wordDoc.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                print(cell.text)
```